# React: how to fix this spinner?

Tags: reactjs

I have a spinner but it works while the page is rendering and I also need it to work when I click the LoadMore button, I don't understand how
Here is the link [Spinner](https://github.com/Monerk98/goit-react-hw-03-image-finder/blob/main/src/components/App.js)

Comment: You need to include the code in the question, if the code from the link you provided will change or will be removed then the question will be obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `this.setState` with setting status to `pending` in first lines of `loadMore` method, or better call it in `fetchImageApi`, just like this:

```
fetchImageApi = () => {
    const { searchbar, page } = this.state;
    this.setState({status: 'pending'}, () => {
        imageApi(searchbar, page)
          .then((images) => {
            if (images.total === 0) {
              this.setState({ error: "No any picture", status: "rejected" });
            } else {
              this.setState((prevState) => ({
               result: [...prevState.result, ...images.hits],
               status: "resolved",
               page: prevState.page + 1,
               searchbar: searchbar,
              }));
            }
          })
          .catch((error) => this.setState({ error, status: "rejected" }));
   }
  };
```

There is callback as a second argument of `setState` method, which means that your callback code will be executed right after react updates its state, so you don't have to write `await` logic for your code.